# Out of order BufferInfo.presentationTimeUs timestamps in mediacodec decoder

Tags: java, android, android-mediacodec

I am getting irregular newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs because of which if I put Thread.sleep to slow down the playback, a lot of frames are dropped.

Actually, with Surface the frames timestamps are synchronized automatically with system timestamp without sleep, however it does not work with giving output to OpenGLES. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#releaseOutputBuffer(int,%20long)

I thought `mExtractor.getSampleTime()` is the problem but even after removing it, the problem is still there.

```
package com.example.app;

import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaExtractor;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;


public final class MediaCodecDecoder {

    private static final String VIDEO = "video/";
    private static final String TAG = "MediaCodecDecoder";
    private final Surface mSurface;
    private final String mClipPath;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder = null;
    private MediaCodec mVideoDecoder;
    private MediaExtractor mExtractor;
    private Boolean mVideoDecoderRunning = false;
    private Thread mVideoDecoderThread;
    private int mDropCount;
    private int mRenderCount;
    private int mFramerate = 30;

    public MediaCodecDecoder(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Surface surface, String clipPath) {
        this.mClipPath = clipPath;
        this.mSurface = surface;
        this.mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    }

    public void start() {
        mDropCount = 0;
        mRenderCount = 0;
        mExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
        try {
            mExtractor.setDataSource(mClipPath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int index = 0; index <= mExtractor.getTrackCount(); index++) {
            MediaFormat format = mExtractor.getTrackFormat(index);
            String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
            if (mime != null && mime.startsWith(VIDEO)) {
                mExtractor.selectTrack(index);
                try {
                    mVideoDecoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    Log.i(TAG, "format : " + format);
                    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, 65536);
                    mFramerate = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE);
                    mVideoDecoder.configure(format, mSurface, null, 0 /* Decode */);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        mVideoDecoder.start();
        mVideoDecoderThread = new videoDecoderHandler(false);
        mVideoDecoderThread.start();
    }


    public void stop() {
        mVideoDecoderRunning = false;
        try {
            mVideoDecoderThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Clear the surface
        if (mSurfaceHolder != null) {
            mSurfaceHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
            mSurfaceHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.OPAQUE);
        }

        Log.v("Extended Stats", "drop Count: " + mDropCount);
        Log.v("Extended Stats", "rendered Count: " + mRenderCount);
        Log.v("Extended Stats", "Total Frames Decoded: " + (mRenderCount + mDropCount));
    }


    class videoDecoderHandler extends Thread {
        boolean endOfStream;

        public videoDecoderHandler(boolean endOfStream) {
            this.endOfStream = endOfStream;
        }

        //method where the thread execution will start
        public void run() {
            //logic to execute in a thread
            mVideoDecoderRunning = true;
            MediaCodec.BufferInfo newBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mVideoDecoder.getInputBuffers();
            ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = mVideoDecoder.getOutputBuffers();
            long startNs = System.nanoTime();
            int generateIndex = 0;

            while (mVideoDecoderRunning) {
                int index = mVideoDecoder.dequeueInputBuffer(1000);
                if (index >= 0) {
                    // fill inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex] with valid data
                    ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[index];
                    int sampleSize = mExtractor.readSampleData(inputBuffer, 0);

                    if (mExtractor.advance() && sampleSize > 0) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "index " + index + " mFramerate " + mFramerate + " mExtractor.getSampleTime() " +
                                mExtractor.getSampleTime() + " PresentationTime " +
                                (startNs / 1000 + computePresentationTime(generateIndex, mFramerate)));
                        // mVideoDecoder.queueInputBuffer(index, 0, sampleSize, startNs / 1000 + mExtractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
                        mVideoDecoder.queueInputBuffer(index, 0, sampleSize, startNs / 1000 +
                                computePresentationTime(generateIndex, 30), 0);
                        generateIndex++;
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "InputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
                        mVideoDecoder.queueInputBuffer(
                                index,
                                0,
                                0,
                                0,
                                MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM
                        );
                    }
                }
                int outIndex = mVideoDecoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(newBufferInfo, 1000);

                switch (outIndex) {
                    case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");
                        outputBuffers = mVideoDecoder.getOutputBuffers();
                        break;
                    case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED format : " +
                                mVideoDecoder.getOutputFormat());
                        break;
                    case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
                        Log.d(TAG, "INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.d(TAG, "outIndex " + outIndex + " newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs " +
                                newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs);
                        boolean render = newBufferInfo.size != 0;
                        long currentNs = System.nanoTime();
                        if (!render) {
                            mVideoDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, false);
                        } else if (currentNs / 1000 - newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs > 30000) {
                            mVideoDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, false);
                            mDropCount++; // drop if more than 30ms late
                        } else {
                            try {
                                if ((newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs - currentNs / 1000) / 1000 > 0) {
                                    Thread.sleep((newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs - currentNs / 1000) / 1000);
                                }
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            mVideoDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true);
                            mRenderCount++;
                        }
                }

                // All decoded frames have been rendered, we can stop playing now
                if ((newBufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "OutputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
                    break;
                }

                if (endOfStream) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            mVideoDecoder.stop();
            mVideoDecoder.release();
            mExtractor.release();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Generates the presentation time for frame N, in microseconds.
     */
    private static long computePresentationTime(int frameIndex, int FRAME_RATE) {
        return (132 + Long.valueOf(frameIndex) * 1000000
                / Long.valueOf(FRAME_RATE));
    }

}
```

This class takes the mp4 video `clipPath`, and has `start` and `stop` functions which start and stop decoding the mp4 video to the passed `surface`.

Here are the logs

```
04-21 20:49:35.875 3595 3971 D MediaCodecDecoder: index 0 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 9666666 PresentationTime 362231984
04-21 20:49:35.879 3595 3971 D MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 14 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 361965317
04-21 20:49:35.884 3595 3971 D MediaCodecDecoder: index 1 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 9800000 PresentationTime 362265317
04-21 20:49:35.888 3595 3971 D MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 2 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 362131984
04-21 20:49:35.894 1124 3960 E OMX-VDEC-1080P: Unable to convey fps info to driver, performance might be affected
04-21 20:49:35.962 3595 3971 D MediaCodecDecoder: index 2 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 9766666 PresentationTime 362298650
04-21 20:49:35.969 3595 3971 D MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 6 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 362098650
04-21 20:49:35.973 3595 3971 D MediaCodecDecoder: index 3 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 9900000 PresentationTime 362331984
04-21 20:49:35.988 1124 3960 E OMX-VDEC-1080P: Unable to convey fps info to driver, performance might be affected
04-21 20:49:35.990 3595 3971 D MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 13 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 362165317
04-21 20:49:35.993 1124 3960 E OMX-VDEC-1080P: Unable to convey fps info to driver, performance might be affected
04-21 20:49:36.000 3595 3971 D MediaCodecDecoder: index 0 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 9866666 PresentationTime 362365317
04-21 20:49:36.003 3595 3971 D MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 5 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 362065317
04-21 20:49:36.005 3595 3971 D MediaCodecDecoder: index 1 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 9833333 PresentationTime 362398650
04-21 20:49:36.007 3595 3971 D MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 3 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 362265317
04-21 20:49:36.013 1124 3960 E OMX-VDEC-1080P: Unable to convey fps info to driver, performance might be affected
04-21 20:49:36.096 3595 3971 D MediaCodecDecoder: index 2 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 10033333 PresentationTime 362431984
04-21 20:49:36.102 3595 3971 D MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 4 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 362231984
04-21 20:49:36.108 3595 3971 D MediaCodecDecoder: index 3 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 9966666 PresentationTime 362465317
04-21 20:49:36.111 3595 3971 D MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 15 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 362198650



04-21 20:49:40.614 3595 3595 V Extended Stats: drop Count: 232
04-21 20:49:40.614 3595 3595 V Extended Stats: rendered Count: 192
04-21 20:49:40.615 3595 3595 V Extended Stats: Total Frames Decoded: 424
```

Here are the logs with

```
                         mVideoDecoder.queueInputBuffer(index, 0, sampleSize, startNs / 1000 + mExtractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
//                        mVideoDecoder.queueInputBuffer(index, 0, sampleSize, startNs / 1000 +
//                                computePresentationTime(generateIndex, 30), 0);
```

```
2021-11-09 15:36:33.898 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: index 0 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 64798066 PresentationTime 907904455
2021-11-09 15:36:33.899 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 14 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 907735489
2021-11-09 15:36:33.910 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: index 1 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 64898166 PresentationTime 907937788
2021-11-09 15:36:33.912 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 15 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 907902323
2021-11-09 15:36:33.969 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: index 2 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 64864800 PresentationTime 907971122
2021-11-09 15:36:33.970 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 8 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 907802223
2021-11-09 15:36:33.973 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: index 3 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 64964900 PresentationTime 908004455
2021-11-09 15:36:33.975 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 9 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 907935690
2021-11-09 15:36:33.999 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: index 4 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 64931533 PresentationTime 908037788
2021-11-09 15:36:34.002 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 11 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 907868956
2021-11-09 15:36:34.004 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: index 5 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 65031633 PresentationTime 908071122
2021-11-09 15:36:34.005 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 6 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 908002423
2021-11-09 15:36:34.065 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: index 6 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 64998266 PresentationTime 908104455
2021-11-09 15:36:34.068 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 4 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 908069156
2021-11-09 15:36:34.131 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: index 7 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 65098366 PresentationTime 908137788
2021-11-09 15:36:34.132 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 3 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 907969056
2021-11-09 15:36:34.133 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: index 8 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 65065000 PresentationTime 908171122
2021-11-09 15:36:34.134 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 7 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 908135890
2021-11-09 15:36:34.209 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: index 9 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 65165099 PresentationTime 908204455
2021-11-09 15:36:34.211 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 13 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 908035790
2021-11-09 15:36:34.213 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: index 10 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 65131733 PresentationTime 908237788
2021-11-09 15:36:34.215 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 5 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 908202623
2021-11-09 15:36:34.270 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: index 11 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 65231833 PresentationTime 908271122
2021-11-09 15:36:34.273 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 16 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 908102523
2021-11-09 15:36:34.275 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: index 0 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 65198466 PresentationTime 908304455
2021-11-09 15:36:34.277 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 12 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 908269356
2021-11-09 15:36:34.331 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: index 1 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 65265199 PresentationTime 908337788
2021-11-09 15:36:34.333 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 14 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 908169256
2021-11-09 15:36:34.334 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: index 2 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 65331933 PresentationTime 908371122
2021-11-09 15:36:34.335 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 10 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 908336089
2021-11-09 15:36:34.398 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: index 3 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 65298566 PresentationTime 908404455
2021-11-09 15:36:34.401 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 8 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 908235990
2021-11-09 15:36:34.402 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: index 4 mFramerate 30 mExtractor.getSampleTime() 65398666 PresentationTime 908437788
2021-11-09 15:36:34.403 6051-6106/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 15 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 908402823
2021-11-09 15:36:34.544 6051-6098/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/SurfaceUtils: disconnecting from surface 0x733202f010, reason disconnectFromSurface

2021-11-09 15:36:34.581 6051-6051/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 V/Extended Stats: drop Count: 909
2021-11-09 15:36:34.581 6051-6051/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 V/Extended Stats: rendered Count: 1044
2021-11-09 15:36:34.581 6051-6051/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 V/Extended Stats: Total Frames Decoded: 1953
```

Here are the logs with

```
mVideoDecoder.queueInputBuffer(index, 0, sampleSize, mExtractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
```

```
2021-02-23 02:36:10.112 5149-5331/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 0 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 15515500
2021-02-23 02:36:10.119 5149-5331/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 10 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 15415400
2021-02-23 02:36:10.178 5149-5331/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 4 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 15582233
2021-02-23 02:36:10.183 5149-5331/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 8 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 15482133
2021-02-23 02:36:10.245 5149-5331/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 14 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 15648966
2021-02-23 02:36:10.252 5149-5331/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 6 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 15548866
2021-02-23 02:36:10.278 5149-5331/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 12 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 15682333
2021-02-23 02:36:10.283 5149-5331/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 3 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 15615600
2021-02-23 02:36:10.345 5149-5331/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 1 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 15749066
2021-02-23 02:36:10.412 5149-5331/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 9 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 15815800
2021-02-23 02:36:10.430 5149-5331/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 2 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 15715700
2021-02-23 02:36:10.478 5149-5331/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 7 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 15882533
2021-02-23 02:36:10.482 5149-5331/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 15 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 15782433
2021-02-23 02:36:10.545 5149-5331/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 5 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 15949266
2021-02-23 02:36:10.550 5149-5331/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 13 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 15849166
2021-02-23 02:36:10.612 5149-5331/org.codeaurora.qmedia2 D/MediaCodecDecoder: outIndex 0 newBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs 16015999
```

By default `int outIndex = mVideoDecoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(newBufferInfo, 1000);` should output frames in display order (which is the timestamp order) as I have checked in the documentation but the timestamps are out of order.

For some reason, the video playback seems smooth even with out of order timestamps and I am utterly confused.

Comment: Can someone comment if I am doing this right?

Comment: Maybe you should start with what you're trying to accomplish, I'm having a hard time understanding what problem you're solving and what does not work.

Comment: During usual decode the playback is very fast. I want to limit it by using sleep. However, the frame timestamps are coming out of order making a lot of frames delayed too much and getting dropped.

Comment: I want to just limit the framerate.

Comment: OpenGLES is using `SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener` to check for frames.

Comment: What I was trying to convey is that you should add some introduction to the question. You should not expect people to read through the code to understand what you are doing. Make sure to include information such as what you are decoding, what is the source of this data, what is the reason you're doing this manually instead of using some third-party library or Android components which would solve this for you and so on. It would be a shame to let all those bounty points just disappear, but you need to put more effort into explaining what you're doing here.

Comment: I've made it as simple to understand as possible for someone who would be knowing about mediacodec. If someone has any doubt, I've included the entire code. I am using mediacodec and not something like mediarecorder (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) because it is newer and has more capabilities which I would like to use later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. It was in `dequeueInputBuffer` part.
I was doing `mExtractor.advance()` beforehand in if statement.

The correct implementation is as follows

```
int index = mVideoDecoder.dequeueInputBuffer(1000);
if (index >= 0) {
    // fill inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex] with valid data
    ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[index];
    int sampleSize = mExtractor.readSampleData(inputBuffer, 0);

    if (sampleSize >= 0) {
        mVideoDecoder.queueInputBuffer(index, 0, sampleSize,
                mExtractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "InputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
        mVideoDecoder.queueInputBuffer(index, 0, 0,
                0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
    }
    mExtractor.advance();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've notices a couple of problems on your code.

First, you shouldn't compute presentation time by yourself since if the video has B frames, the presentation time of frames might not always come in increasing order. Causing the frame timestamps seems to come out of order.

https://ottverse.com/i-p-b-frames-idr-keyframes-differences-usecases/

Second, you shouldn't drop the frame based on the time you passed it into the decoder. Decoder some time needs multiple frame to be passed before outputting a new frame, so it may take some times for the decoder to decode a particular frame.
Rather you should calculate it based on the first frame rendered.

```kotlin
// when passing frame to decoder
sampleTime = mExtractor.getSampleTime()
if (firstFrame) {
   firstSampleTime = sampleTime
}
mVideoDecoder.queueInputBuffer(index, 0, sampleSize, sampleTime,0);




// when receiving the frame from decoder
currrent = System.nanoTime()/ 1000
if (firstFrame) {
   firstFrameReceived = current
}

receivedDelta =  current - firstFrame
presentationTimeDelta = mBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs - firstSampleTime

if (receivedDelta - presentatinTimeDelta > 30ms) {
    // Drop frame
}
```

Comment: As for your second suggestion, the net effect is just to add some ms to 30 in `(receivedDelta - presentatinTimeDelta > 30ms)`. It might reduce the loss of some frames but not solve my out of order issue.

Comment: For your first comment, I had already tried `mExtractor.getSampleTime()`. Please check more details added in the question.

Comment: I dont think it matters but, can you try passing extractor time as it is without adding startTimeNs/1000, and check if output timestamp is in order. As far as is know it is guaranteed by cts to be in order. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/5780add/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/DecoderTest.java#169. , Btw can you tell me what device you are using?

Comment: I did that. Check the updated question. The cts test you gave is very interesting, I will check further. I can tell you that my device is running stock Android 10.